# Can't access tomcat server from LAN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, tomcat

Launched tomcat server on host(windows) and responds to requests from outside the network. However I cant make it work trough host-only network(or any other lan). I tried with VMworkstation and VirtualBox. Seems like tomcat doesn't respond... 
What I already done:
Tried setting up WAMP and it works in host-only
Tried dissabling firewalls
Tried altering server.xml Current connector configuration is as follows:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           address="0.0.0.0"
           allowHostHeaderMismatch="true"
           rejectIllegalHeaderName="false"/>
```

Scrolling trough documentation I found this [docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwdIM.png) Maybe the default package protection is preventing me from accessing tomcat from internal network? How to dissable it though?
Tomcat version 9.0.0.M9

Comment: Wamp? Which host-only are you going to use, Virtualbox or VMware??

Comment: Preferably virtualbox, but what does it matter because it's not a vm problem? WAMP - windows apache mysql php server. Like tomcat, just for PHP.

Comment: No point adding wamp info, I know what it is and only adds noise. And it matters on the VM manager because it's on their settings. You'd check the host only network configuration, did you create it on Virtualbox or in the OS?

Comment: I dissagre, it shows that host only is configured correctly and packets in fact goes trough. In virtualbox i added host only adapter and in guest I configured a static IP for it. What else is there?